# Visual studio does not break on user-handled exception in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

Whenever I have a try/catch statement in my own code, the Exception still breaks to debugger.

- I can turn off the check **Break when this exception type is
  thrown**.
  I *don't* want to do that because I do want to break in all other cases that I don't have a try/catch.
- I can turn **Except when thrown from this dll**. I don't want to that for the exact same reason. There are valid reasons in that DLL why I want to break when I do not try/catch it myself.

I just want to **not break** when I have a try/catch statement, because I am already handling it so I don't want to be bugged by every external call that is failing.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

This mainly seems to be a problem with ASP.NET. Probably because there is one big try/catch per request in the outermost ASP.NET layer.

So what I'm looking for in a way is something like:

Break only try/catched in *external code*.

[image: Visual studio debugger]

Comment: Is this your code or an external library?

Comment: This is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your question but if you just take out "Break when this exception type is thrown" you should have the exact behaviour you want. The debugger will still break if the exception isn't caught. The only thing this checkbox does is tell the debugger to break **even if the exception got caught**.

If this is not the behaviour you want I may need some clarification to understand your question.

Edit:
Since you've now edited your question and you seem to be looking for "Break only try/catched in external code.", I can only tell you that I wouldn't know of such a feature and have never used anything like that. That does not mean it doesn't exist though.

Comment: Hi @Joelius, maybe it has to with ASP.NET that has one big try/catch in the outermost code. When I uncheck this box it will never break anymore. So also not when the Exception is not catched (in my code).

Comment: Huh this is weird. I used a lot of ASP recently and had no issues like that whatsoever. Did you place that try/catch you mentioned yourself or are you talking about something from asp? Because if that's from you please remove it :)
Also have you searched for all "try" apperances in your code? Maybe there is one catch which swallows everything that you've missed.

Comment: Hi @Joelius, are you using ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? I don't have a try/catch encapsulated, but I think there is one in the ASP.NET to prevent your application from crashing - and just show the yellow error page.

Comment: I use Core. Maybe you're thinking of app.UseExceptionPage in the Pipeline? Or what do you mean by "yellow error page"? You can comment out UseExceptionPage and UseDevelopperExceptionPage in the Startup class and see if this helps (you'd have to take out the tick from the exception). Also if you used a template there might be a check if the environment is development and only then it would add the exception page. Check those things in the Startup.cs and try some combinations, maybe you'll get it like that.